Do vampires get more powerful in "vampire mode"?
In Buffy the Vampire Slayer, and Angel after that, vampires have 2 faces: They have their everyday (mostly) human faces, but at will they can take on a more brutal apperance, fangs out, brows ridges giving a menacing look.
Somewhere in a vague memory, I seem to remember this being referred to as 'vamping out', and in the show it also looks like that in this form, vampires gain additional strength and resilience.
Is this canonically addressed in the shows, and am I correct in thinking that this 'alternative' more vampiric form increases thier abilities? I think in season one when the Masters cult is about to attack the library, Buffy even tells Angel to "put your game face on" in preparation for a wave of vampires...

https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Vampire#Powers_and_abilities

@dosco in the link you've left it says 'also appeared to increase'.  the use of 'appeared on a fan created wiki leaves my question still unanswered as to if its canonically addressedand confirmed that yes thier strength does increase.

@MattBartlett - It's a good job he posted it as a comment then, isn't it?
